# React Natve CLI, synchronization of app versioning / build number

Tags: react-native, yarn-v2

What is the best approach to handle app versioning (MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH BUILD#) using yarn / cli when building an app and then using yarn to set the numbers?  I'm having trouble getting any of the suggestions to work (like react-native-version-number) that will also bump the build number, as well as display the version info in the app itself